# Populate an NSArray via an NSDictionary which is populated via a .plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Verb data read, sorted and assigned to a dictionary
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"VerbDictionary" ofType:@"plist"];    
    NSDictionary *verbDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSArray *verbs = [verbDictionary allKeys];
    NSArray *vSorted = [verbs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSString *selectedVerb = [vSorted objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *vArray = [verbDictionary objectForKey:selectedVerb];
    self.verbArrayData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:vArray];
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Error message I'm getting:

[image]

(from https://plus.google.com/u/0/113629344949177123204/posts/SwHzXL6kvvJ)

The `self.verbArrayData` is not populating from the `vArray`.  `self.verbDataArray` is `nil` and it shouldn't be.

I have tried this from scratch and I have done this before, actually, in the past, but via iOS 4 and Release/retain memory management.  This is the first pure iOS 5 ARC app I have started.

Any ideas?

Comment: that's not an error message. It is a view that shows your variables. Do you just have a breakpoint on self.verbArrayData?!

Comment: You are correct, Matthias. No an error message, but the array is NOT populating as it should.  I cannot figure out why self.verbDataArray is not initializing from the local NSArray variable vSorted.  For self.verbDataArray, the code specifically alloc's and initfromarray:vArray.

I pasted a code snippet yesterday and that code snippet is no longer appearing on the web page via Safari - works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Are you using GDB or LLDB as the debugger? In xCode 4.3.1, LLDB has a bug where ivars occasionally show the wrong values. Try switching to GDB or upgrading to xCode 4.3.2.

Comment: How is verbArrayData declared?  Is it possible it's getting deallocated before you actually look at it?  Putting a few NSLog statements in there so you can see what's actually getting assigned to those variables would probably help.

Comment: I figured it out... But I am not sure why it works.
Self.verbArrayData is invalid.  However, just verbArrayData works just fine.

So, I changed self.verbArrayData = [[NSArray.. to verbArrayData = [[NSArray.. and it compiled and ran fine.  

So, self.verbArrayData is the getter not the setter in this case; I think.

THanks -

Comment: @Flyingdiver - with ARC, XCODE 4.3.1 and iOS5, ARC does not allow deallocating.   The screen shot of the breakpoint indicated that the local variable had data, but the NSArray, after assignment, did not.  However, one cannot 'set' with self.... in this regard, as I have learned.

Comment: I didn't say you deallocated it, but it will get deallocated.  The compiler adds the deallocate statements where they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... But I am not sure why it works. Self.verbArrayData is invalid. However, just verbArrayData works just fine. So, I changed self.verbArrayData = [[NSArray...] TO just verbArrayData = [[NSArray...] and it compiled and ran fine. So, self.verbArrayData is the getter not the setter in this case; I think. THanks - –

Comment: That's almost certainly a problem with your declaration of the verbArrayData property, which is why I asked you to post the code where you declare it.